# Django test returns 404 error

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm using the django test framwork to test my API. I have a simple view that returns "ok" at the address GET `http://localhost:8000/v1/ping/`. When I run the server and I test this with Chrome, it works well. However, when I launch a test on it, I get a 404 error. This is my test:

```
def test_ping(self):
    c = Client()
    response = c.get('/v1/ping/')
    print response.content
    print response.status_code
```

and the response:

```
<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /v1/ping/ was not found on this server.</p>
404
```

Comment: how are you testing and how are you running the server?

Comment: I run the server using ./manage.py runserver and I test using ./manage.py test

Comment: You don't need to run development server to perform tests and the rest is in @kreld's response

Comment: Could I see your urls.py? in particular where the ping endpoint is defined

Comment: `from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from core_API import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
    url(r'^v1/accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^v1/content/', include('content.urls')),
    url(r'^v1/ping/$', views.Ping.as_view()),
)`

Answer (score 1):

The `get` method on Django's Test Client takes a relative path as an argument. Have you tried `response = c.get('/v1/ping/')`?

Comment: Yes, actually, my normal test is with a relative path. The full path was just a test for me. Both have the same response. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error: I use `rest_framework_swagger` and there was a test file in it. I deleted it and everything is OK now.